# Accessing error from react-hook-form using reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, reactstrap

I created a form with reactstrap and react-hook-form. Why are my errors not displaying?

**Dummy section which renders text input:**

```
function DummySection() {
  const { control } = useForm();
  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        name="dummyName"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field: { onChange, ref }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
          <TextInput onChange={onChange} innerRef={ref} error={error} />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Text input with error:**

```
function TextInput({ onChange, value, innerRef, error }) {
  const updateText = (e) => {
    onChange(e);
    // do something else below
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        name="dummyName"
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => updateText(e)}
        value={value}
        innerRef={innerRef}
      />
      {error && "Cannot be blank"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Submit Button**

```
function SubmitBtn() {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return <Button onClick={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)()}>Submit</Button>;
}
```

Thanks.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-driscoll-zcy6y?file=/src/App.js:892-1078)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jamfie, you are using different `useForm` for each component.

Your form need to have the same instance, you can do that by using [useformcontext](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext) or by passing props to components.

Also, you do not need Controller for this thing,
here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sound-mw026?file=/src/App.js) shows how you can use reactstrap with react-hook-form.

You can also follow [this answer](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/5720#issuecomment-867472627) in github issue.

Comment: Thanks! I need to control the state hence I used Controller. Using useformcontext and ensuring all form components are using the same instance did the job.